# extract column based on certain grouping and pattern Unix

Tags: regex, awk, grep

I have a file as below:

```
header1 header2 header3 header4 header5   
A123 ABC EFG ABC PQR       
A456 ABC JKL DEF ABC   
A789 ABC CDE HIJ ABC   
B123 CDE KLM MNO EFG   
B456 CDE NOP MNO CCC   
B789 EFG QRS MNO AAA
```

As you can see, there are two group start with A & B in column 1. The pattern within the file show all ABC for group A in column 2 and all MNO for group B in column 4. I wish to extract column 2 and column 4 together with the headers. So eventually the output is as below:

```
header1 header2 header4   
A123 ABC ABC        
A456 ABC DEF    
A789 ABC HIJ    
B123 CDE MNO    
B456 CDE MNO    
B789 EFG MNO
```

Is there any way to do so with unix command? Appreciate for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply with `awk`:

```
awk '{print $1" "$2" "$4}' file
```

**Result:**

```
header1 header2 header4
A123 ABC ABC
A456 ABC DEF
A789 ABC HIJ
B123 CDE MNO
B456 CDE MNO
B789 EFG MNO
```

Answer (score 0):

Even shorter with **awk**:

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$4}' File
```

By default, the `OFS` (output field seperator) in `awk` is a single `space`. So just print the `1st`, `2nd` and `4th` fields in each line.